# Why does a robot with navigation stack sometimes rotate in place

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, everyone.

I'm using nav stack and it works well.
However, sometimes a robot stops in its track and rotates in place.
**It isn't a kind of recovery behavior.**
And I think that it often occurs when I set maximum velocity to small value(eg. 0.1[m/s]).

**What is the trigger for the rotation?**

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59647/why-does-a-robot-with-navigation-stack-sometimes-rotate-in-place./) by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 721 on 2013-03-31

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Peter Listov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3071/peter-listov/) on 2013-04-01**:
As far as I remember it's one of the recovery behaviors. It happens when a robot cannot find feasible local path (control).

**Comment by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on 2013-04-11**:
Thank you for your comment ! When I set maximum velocity to large value(eg. 0.3～1.0[m/s]), It works well and rotation doesn't often occur. So I think it's not a problem about local path...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [rotate_recovery](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rotate_recovery) is indeed usually [expected](http://www.ros.org/wiki/move_base#Expected_Robot_Behavior) to be [one of the two recovery behaviours](http://www.ros.org/wiki/nav_core#RecoveryBehavior). Unless you configured it else.

Are you sure there isn't another possible reason for it to rotate? You can visualize the global and local paths and obstacles etc in RViz to see if the current plan fails.

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2013-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [moyashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2104/moyashi/) on 2013-04-11**:
Thank you for your answer ! Global planner generates global path and it looks available. However, when maximum_velocity is very small, robot often rotates in place. I can't find another possible reason ...

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-04-12**:
Check via `rostopic echo cmd_vel` whether the robot is commanded to rotate in place or not and just cannot perform what the navigation wants it to do, e.g. a close curve, resulting in in-place-rotation. Which robot do you use?